# Run a program in a new window with sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm programming using Sublime Text 2 and I was wondering if there is a way to run programs in a new window. For a while I was using Geany as my python editor and when I would run a program, the program would start in a window called geany_run_script.sh.  Is there a way to acheive what I would like? Thanks.

(If it helps, Im running Linux and programming with Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by window you mean a new tab/buffer then this:
https://github.com/vhyza/exec-in-window
is exactly what you want.   You can get it via Package Control.